# How to fix propect_lists subpanel in accounts, contacts and leads?

Tags: sugarcrm

There is a description by Robert Lausegger ([iscon group](http://iscon.at/index.php/docman/cat_view/12-verschiedenes)) which made it possible to show prospect list in a subpanel in other modules. [But since SugarCRM 6.3 this wasn't working anymore.](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111259540860581794293/posts/GwZowKcKv8n)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vardefs` have to be changed to:

```
$dictionary["Lead"]["fields"]["prospect_lists"] = array(
  'name' => 'prospect_lists',
```

and the `layoutdefs`

```
'get_subpanel_data' => 'prospect_lists',
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The site referenced in the above link was in German, so, courtesy of the author of that site, Robert Laussegger of the iscon group (www.iscongroup.net) in Germany, here is the english language version of the method.  I used this on SugarCRM CE v 6.5 running on a LAMP stack with CentOS 6.4 base and it worked fine.  Adjust to your install as appropriate.

The example given shows how to add a Target List (called Prospect List internally with SugarCRM) to a Contact DetailView; adjust the settings for Leads, ...

If the directories shown do not exist, create them, being careful to match not only spelling but capitalization.  You will be adding 3 files in 3 separate directories.

Remember to set the file permissions and owner/group to allow the server to access the files created.

When finished adding the files and setting the permissions, as a CRM administrator, run:
    Admin -> Repair -> Rebuild Relationships (to flush cache)
    Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild

Create the following files in the directories shown:

In /var/www/html//custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Language
-Create file en_us.prospectlist_in_contacts_language.php 
and into the file put
(the part of the filename " prospectlist_in_contacts_language" can be whatever you want, as long as you use the prefix "en_us." (for  US English language) and the suffix ".php")

```
<?php
$mod_strings['LBL_PROSPECTLISTS_CONTACTS_FROM_PROSPECTLISTS_TITLE'] = 'Target Lists';
?>
```

In /var/www/html//custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Layoutdefs
Create file prospectlist_in_contacts_layoutdef.php 
and into the file put
(the part of the filename " prospectlist_in_contacts_layoutdef" can be whatever you want, as long as you use the suffix ".php")

```
<?php 
$layout_defs["Contacts"]["subpanel_setup"]["prospect_list_contacts"] = array ( 
'order' => 100, 
'module' => 'ProspectLists', 
'subpanel_name' => 'default', 
'sort_order' => 'asc', 
'sort_by' => 'id', 
'title_key' => 'LBL_PROSPECTLISTS_CONTACTS_FROM_PROSPECTLISTS_TITLE', 
'get_subpanel_data' => 'prospect_list_contacts', 
'top_buttons' => 
array ( 
0 => 
array ( 
'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate', 
), 
1 => 
array ( 
'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton', 
'mode' => 'MultiSelect', 
), 
), 
);
?>
```

In /var/www/html//custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Vardefs
Create file prospectlist_in_contacts_vardef.php 
and into the file put
(the part of the filename " prospectlist_in_contacts_vardef" can be whatever you want, as long as you use the suffix ".php")

```
<?php 
$dictionary["Contact"]["fields"]["prospect_list_contacts"] = array ( 
'name' => 'prospect_list_contacts', 
'type' => 'link', 
'relationship' => 'prospect_list_contacts', 
'source' => 'non-db', 
'vname' => 'LBL_PROSPECTLISTS_CONTACTS_FROM_PROSPECTLISTS_TITLE', 
);
$dictionary["Contact"]["fields"]["prospect_list_name"] = array (

'name' => 'prospect_list_name',
'rname' => 'name',
'id_name' => 'prospect_list_id',
'vname' => 'LBL_PROSPECTLISTS_CONTACTS_FROM_PROSPECTLISTS_TITLE',
'type' => 'relate',
'link' => 'prospect_lists',
'table' => 'prospect_lists',
'isnull' => 'true',
'module' => 'ProspectLists',
'dbType' => 'char',
'len' => '255',
'source' => 'non-db',
);
?>
```

Reset owner/permissions

Run, as CRM administrator
    Admin -> Repair -> Rebuild Relationships (to flush cache)
    Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild